Why does my C# API integration test only run in Release mode and not in Debug mode?
I have a C# test project with an API integration test that only runs successfully when the Configuration Manager is set to "Release" and I execute the test in Release mode. The test fails to run in Debug mode. ( simply skip tests without any reason (1. picture) ).

Here are a few points I have checked already:

Verified that there are no #if DEBUG preprocessor directives affecting the test.
Checked that both configurations build without errors.

More info:
Custom.Api.IntegrationTests:

public abstract class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    public IConfigurationBuilder ConfigurationBuilder { get; set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    protected CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        var projectDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var configPath = Path.Combine(projectDir, "appsettings.test.common.json");

        ConfigurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(configPath);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var databaseSeedFileName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DatabaseSettings:DBSeedFileName");
        var fullConnectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DatabaseSettings:FullConnectionString");
        var toCreateConnectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DatabaseSettings:ToCreateConnectionString");


        InitializeDatabase(databaseSeedFileName!, toCreateConnectionString);

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<CalendarEntities>));

            services.AddMySql<CalendarEntities>(fullConnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(fullConnectionString));
        });
    }

    public CalendarEntities CreateDbContext()
    {
        var scope = Services.CreateScope();
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CalendarEntities>();
        return db;
    }

    private void InitializeDatabase(string databaseSeedFileName, string toCreateConnectionString)
    {
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(toCreateConnectionString);

        connection.Open();

        var fullPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), databaseSeedFileName);

        var script = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);

        using var command = new MySqlCommand(script, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

Calendar.Api.IntegrationTests:
public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    public ApiWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        var projectDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var configPath = Path.Combine(projectDir, "appsettings.test.json");

        ConfigurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(configPath, optional: false);

        Configuration = ConfigurationBuilder.Build();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddOptions();

            services.AddHttpClient<IApiLoginHelper, ApiLoginHelper>();

            services.Configure<PathSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(PathSettings)));
            services.Configure<TokenRequestSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenRequestSettings)));
        });
    }
}


public class UsersControllerTestsWithAuth : IClassFixture<ApiIntegrationTestContext>
{
    private readonly ApiIntegrationTestContext _fixture;
    private readonly IApiLoginHelper _apiLoginHelper;
    private readonly PathSettings _pathSettings;

    public UsersControllerTestsWithAuth(
        ApiIntegrationTestContext fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;

        using var scope = _fixture.Factory.Services.CreateScope();
        _pathSettings = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<PathSettings>>().Value;
        _apiLoginHelper = new ApiLoginHelper(scope, _pathSettings.BaseApiUrl);

    }

    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(CreateAsyncTheoryDataWithValidationErrors))]
    public async Task CreateAsync_Should_Return_Validation_Errors(UserToAdd newUser, List<ValidationDto> expectedResults)
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}


Post your code as text. Images can't be copied, compiled or tested. Skipping tests doesn't mean the tests can't run. It means the tests were found but were excluded for some reason, eg due to a flag.

@PanagiotisKanavos That's neither code nor error, it's a screenshot of the test explorer - in this case absolutely fine.

@Julian it's no information at all so not fine at all - except for the existence of the tests and the exclamation mark. We can't guess if the code has a flag, not even what unit test library is used. No messages either. We don't even know what IDE is used

@PanagiotisKanavos I actually voted to close, because of missing details. The image however is fine.

That exclamation mark means there's a message somewhere. You may be able to see it by hovering over the exclamation mark, clicking on the test or checking the Output window

Check if this answer applies to your situation (or anything else on that page, there is a lot)

I edited the question with code.

Are you sure? I see several issues in the code, including attempts to create a database in the host setup, using connection strings outside the ConnectionStrings section. The test may crash because the correct settings file is missing, because the connection strings are different, because InitializeDatabase fails if the database is already initialized


Did you actually check the messages? 2) var configPath = Path.Combine(projectDir, "appsettings.test.json"); can easily be the problem. The current directory is bin/Debug or bin/Release depending on the configuration. Adding a new JSON or text file to a project doesn't automatically copy it to the build folder. You need to change the Build Action from None to Copy if Newer or Copy Always. I've made this mistake way too many times


You should probably simplify and cleanup the factory classes so it's easier to see what's going on. Right now you're creating new Configuration objects, which means any config in the API itself is lost. You could avoid that by just calling builder.Configuration.AddJson("appsettings.test.json",false). Newer config sources override previous ones. You don't need to specify AddMySql again either, if the actual DbContext call uses DatabaseSettings:FullConnectionString as the connection string. The more code you add in rarely used files like test classes, the higher the chance of error

could you try setting up the detailed logging to the code to get more detail where is the issue.
